# Unable to print date format in nodejs using ejs with mysql

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

this is the date format im getting from db. All i want to explode into two numbers

```
 7:00-8:00   //array[0]=7:00 and array[1]=8:00
 9:00-9:30
 14:30-15:00
```

below is the code which i have written. im getting NAN NAN

```
 <% time_slots.forEach((timeslot) =>{
 var str =  timeslot['timing'];            // here im getting  7:00-8:00
 //console.log(str);
 var arr = str.split("-").map(function (val) {   //here spit with("-")
    return +val + 1; });
  %>
      <%- arr %>                              //output NAN NAN
 <% }) %>
```

All i was trying to get like this, array[0]=7:00 and array[1]=8:00

Comment: What you want to do with `return +val + 1;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need [map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) here:

```
str = '7:00-8:00'

test = str.split("-")
console.log(test[0], test[1])
```

Output: `7:00 8:00`

> You are getting `NAN` because inside map function you are doing `+val
>   + 1`, where val is a type of `string`.

Comment: yes you are right. Their is not need of map() using. I thought that map would written me the array. If i would use map() function it should written some value to me. I think it is sending  in string rather in number i have also try with **parseInt** .

Comment: Yes @Vishal `7:00` is string, you can't parse it using `parseInt()`. If you want to do so you need more calculation to parse time into Date obj.